# Solve nonlinear equations with sympy, but i got results with a small imaginary part

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations with Sympy and Python.

The result is almost right, but always with a extremly small imaginary part, and the process is time consuming.

I also try the same computation under Matlab, the result is pretty good and fast.

I know that small imaginary part can be ignored. But I think there must be something wrong in my code which result in slowly and imaginary part. Can any one help me with this?

```
Python:3.6
Sympy:1.1.1
```

```
import sympy
A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1 = (0.0019047619047619048,
                          -1.7494954273533616e-19,
                          0.0004761904761904762,
                          -8.747477136766808e-18,
                          0.047619047619047616,
                          1.0)
A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2 = (8.264462809917356e-05,
                          -0.0,
                          0.00033057851239669424,
                          -0.008264462809917356,
                          -0.03305785123966942,
                          1.0)
k, b = sympy.symbols('k b')
eq1 = B1 ** 2 * b ** 2 + 2 * B1 * D1 * b - 2 * B1 * E1 * b * k - 4 * F1 * B1 * k + D1 ** 2 + 2 * D1 * E1 * k + \
      4 * C1 * D1 * b * k + E1 ** 2 * k ** 2 - 4 * A1 * E1 * b - 4 * A1 * C1 * b ** 2 - 4 * C1 * F1 * k ** 2 - 4 * A1 * F1
eq2 = B2 ** 2 * b ** 2 + 2 * B2 * D2 * b - 2 * B2 * E2 * b * k - 4 * F2 * B2 * k + D2 ** 2 + 2 * D2 * E2 * k + \
      4 * C2 * D2 * b * k + E2 ** 2 * k ** 2 - 4 * A2 * E2 * b - 4 * A2 * C2 * b ** 2 - 4 * C2 * F2 * k ** 2 - 4 * A2 * F2
s=sympy.solve([eq1,eq2],[k,b])
print(s)
```

That's what I got under Python and Sympy, with an extremely small imaginary  part. And it almost takes 10 seconds. That is not acceptable for my whole project.

```
[(1.07269682322063 + 2.8315655624133e-28*I, -27.3048937553762 + 0.e-27*I), 
(1.79271658724978 - 2.83156477591471e-28*I, -76.8585791921325 - 0.e-27*I), 
(2.34194482854222 + 2.83156702952074e-28*I, -19.2027508047623 - 0.e-26*I),
 (5.20930842765403 - 2.83156580622397e-28*I, -105.800442914396 - 7.59430998293648e-28*I)]
```

That's what I got under MATLAB with 'solve'. It's pretty fast. That's what I wanted.

```
k =
       5.2093
       1.7927
       1.0727
       2.3419
b =
       -105.8
      -76.859
      -27.305
      -19.203
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SymPy intends to be a symbolic package, not numeric, so the results should be expected. There is, however, the function `nsolve` that can be used to find numerical solutions. There is no dedicated method (that I am aware of) that will compute all roots of a polynomial -- in this case, a pair of quadratics -- in SymPy/mpmath. You would have to find roots one by one:

```
>>> list(nsolve((eq1, eq2), (k,b), (1, 1)))
[1.07269682322063, -27.3048937553762]
```

But one can use the existing tools to build a solver for such equations. The following is an example (with the potential for lots of numerical issues in corner cases):

```
def n2solve(eq1, eq2, x, y, n):
  """Return numerical solutions for 2 equations in
  x and y where each is polynomial of order 2 or less
  as would be true for equations describing geometrical
  objects.

  Examples
  ========

  >>> n2solve(x**2 + y, y**2 - 3*x*y + 4, x, y, 3)
  (-2.82, -7.96)
  (-1.34, -1.80)
  """
  from sympy.core.containers import Tuple
  from sympy.solvers.solvers import unrad, solve
  eqs = Tuple(eq1, eq2)
  sym = set([x, y])
  assert all(i.free_symbols == sym for i in eqs)
  anx = solve(eq1, x)[0]
  yeq = eq2.subs(x, anx)
  z = unrad(yeq)
  z = z[0] if z else yeq
  yy = real_roots(z)
  def norm(x,y):
    return abs((x**2+y**2).n(2))
  got=[]
  for yi in yy:
    yi = yi.n(n)
    ty = eqs.subs(y, yi)
    for xi in real_roots(ty[0]):
      xi = xi.n(n)
      got.append((norm(*ty.subs(x, xi)), xi, yi))
  return sorted([(x,y) for e,x,y in sorted(got)[:len(got)//2]])
```

This gives the following solutions for the equations posed in the question:

```
[(1.07, -27.3),
(1.79, -76.9),
(2.34, -19.2),
(5.21, -106.)]
```